# Agregar autentificación a endpoints GAE Java

Tags: java, webservice, rest, google-app-engine, endpoint

Estoy generando unos endpoints y funcionan correctamente, sin embargo, quisiera mantener una sesión por cliente para no tener que mandar el correo y contraseña por cada request, pero no estoy muy seguro de como hacerlo.

Este es un ejemplo de uno de mis endpoints

```
@Api(name = "test")
public class MyApi {

@ApiMethod(name = "imprimirHola", httpMethod = "POST")
public Message imprimirHola(Input input) {
    Message message = new Message();
    if(datosCorrectos(input.getMail(), input.getPassword()))
        message.setMessage("Hola");
    else
        message.setMessage("Error de autentificación");
    return message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas [alternativas provistas para autenticar usuarios en los Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users) (recomiendo utilizar **Firebase**) .

En caso de no utilizar ninguno de estos servicios puede aplicar un login propio, por el cual al hacer login se le envía un token al usuario y luego se envia ese token con cada request dentro de un header.

Dentro del método del endpoint incluyes un Objeto del tipo `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` y este se inyectara automáticamente. A través de ese objeto puedes acceder a los headers y verificar que el token sea valido.